# recursively exit rectangle in python

Tags: python, recursion

I try to write a recursive function that accepts a set of arrays of integers and returns the path from the upper left corner to the bottom right, passing only between neighboring cells, where each new cell must be substantially larger than the previous cell.

To get exactly the route, I need to check the four adjacent cells in the following order: right, down, left, and up.

[image]

```
def exit_rectangle_position(array, row, col, l):
    if col + 1 < len(array) and array[row][col+1] > array[row][col]:
        l.append([row,col+1])
        exit_rectangle_position(array, row, col+1, l)
    elif row + 1 < len(array) and array[row+1][col] > array[row][col]:
        l.append([row+1,col])
        exit_rectangle_position(array, row+1, col, l)
    elif col - 1 >= 0 and array[row][col-1] > array[row][col]:
        l.append([row,col-1])
        exit_rectangle_position(array, row, col-1, l)
    elif row - 1 >= 0 and array[row - 1][col] > array[row][col]:
        l.append([row-1,col])
        exit_rectangle_position(array, row-1, col, l)



def exit_rectangle(array):
    l = []
    l.append([0,0])
    exit_rectangle_position(array,0,0,l)
    if [len(array)-1, len(array)-1] in l:
        return l
    return []
```

The problem is that when I get stuck, I do not know how to get back from where I started.
For example the array

```
print(exit_rectangle([[1,2,3],[2,0,5],[3,4,5]]))
```

I have to return

```
# [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

But I get

```
# []
```

Comment: In high-school, this was one example when learning *backtracking* (plane).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive DFS works well here:

```
def exit_rectangle(a, x=None, y=None, seen=None):
  if x is None:
    x = 0
  if y is None:
    y = 0
  if seen is None:
    seen = set()

  if x + 1 == len(a[0]) and y + 1 == len(a):
    # Exit found
    return [(x, y)]

  # Maybe we've been here before
  if (x, y) in seen:
    return None
  seen.add((x, y))

  # Go right
  if x + 1 < len(a[0]) and a[y][x] < a[y][x+1]:
    path = exit_rectangle(a, x+1, y, seen)
    if path is not None:
      return [(x, y)] + path

  # Go left
  if 0 < x and a[y][x] < a[y][x-1]:
    path = exit_rectangle(a, x-1, y, seen)
    if path is not None:
      return [(x, y)] + path

  # Go up
  if 0 < y and a[y][x] < a[y-1][x]:
    path = exit_rectangle(a, x, y-1, seen)
    if path is not None:
      return [(x, y)] + path

  # Go down
  if y + 1 < len(a) and a[y][x] < a[y+1][x]:
    path = exit_rectangle(a, x, y+1, seen)
    if path is not None:
      return [(x, y)] + path

  # Dead end
  return None


print(exit_rectangle([[1,2,3],[2,0,5],[3,4,5]]))
```

Comment: For me it prints `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]`. Do you have an example where the code does not work?